# Selenium / select dropbox?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

i try to use selenium with this site:

https://gesund.bund.de/suchen/aerztinnen-und-aerzte

with the following code:

```
import time
import os, sys

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
# from fake_useragent import UserAgent

if __name__ == '__main__':
  path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1})
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
  srv=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
  driver = webdriver.Chrome (service=srv, options=options)
  waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)

  link = f"https://gesund.bund.de/suchen/aerztinnen-und-aerzte"  
  driver.get (link)
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//input[@id="arztsuche__field_where"]'))).clear()
  time.sleep(0.5)
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//input[@id="arztsuche__field_where"]'))).send_keys("13403")
  time.sleep(0.5)

  # select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@id="arztsuche-fachrichtung-list"]'))
  # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="arztsuche-fachrichtung-list"]'))))    
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="arztsuche-fachrichtung-list"]'))).send_keys("Hausarzt")
```

input("Press!")

I try to select an entry from the combobox "Fachrichtung" i the middle but it is not working. I tried several thing like you can see in the comment:

```
  # select = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//div[@id="arztsuche-fachrichtung-list"]'))
  # driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="arztsuche-fachrichtung-list"]'))))    
  waitWD.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//div[@id="arztsuche-fachrichtung-list"]'))).send_keys("Hausarzt")
```

Tried to use select (but it tells me its no select-element). Tried to click on it - but it is not clickable. And tried to simple assign a text to it - but this is also not working.

How can i automate the element on this site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an Auto Complete form,`Select` won't work here.
You need to identify the element and then click on the element after search result appear on the autocomplete form.

```
waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)

link = "https://gesund.bund.de/suchen/aerztinnen-und-aerzte"  
driver.get (link)
searchstring="13403"
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@id="arztsuche__field_where"]'))).clear()
time.sleep(0.5)
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@id="arztsuche__field_where"]'))).send_keys(searchstring)
time.sleep(0.5)
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='{}']".format(searchstring)))).click()
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

```
waitWD = WebDriverWait (driver, 10)

link = "https://gesund.bund.de/suchen/aerztinnen-und-aerzte"  
driver.get (link)
searchstring="13403"
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@id="arztsuche__field_where"]'))).clear()
time.sleep(0.5)
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//input[@id="arztsuche__field_where"]'))).send_keys(searchstring)
time.sleep(0.5)
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='{}']".format(searchstring)))).click()

waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#arztsuche-fachrichtung"))).click()
secondField='Hausarzt'
waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='{}']".format(secondField)))).click()
```

**BrowserSnapshot**

[image]

Comment: Hello - thanks for replying - i tried your code but it seem not work - i get an errror -
To clarify that: In the first field "Ort, Adresse oder Postleitzahl" there should go 13403 for example - and this allready works.
But what is not working is the second field "Fachrichtung" - there should go for example "Hausarzt".
So i want to have 13404 and Hausarzt selected in this 2 fields finally.

Comment: This is the error i get when i run your code:

`   File "G:\DEV\Fiverr\TRY\alexanderbaa\test.py", line 44, in <module>
    waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='{}']".format(searchstring)))).click()`

Comment: `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="pac-matched">...</span> is not clickable at point (420, 961). Other element would receive the click: <div id="CybotCookiebotDialog" name="CybotCookiebotDialog" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyContentTitle" tabindex="-1" lang="en" dir="ltr" ng-non-bindable="" data-template="slideup"
class="CybotEdge CybotMultilevel CybotCookiebotDialogActive" style="display: flex;">...</div>`

Comment: @Rapid1898, Please check the updated scripts, it is selecting both the fields.

Comment: Thanks - now it worked.
btw: I have to click the cookie-questions with the following code - otherwise it was not working

`      try:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", waitWD.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"]'))))    
        time.sleep(2)
      except:
        pass   `